# Need to bring the 2 years of yield data corresponding each crop in every district from one datafile to another datafile in same format

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-cleaning

I am new to R and struggling to combine two dataframes provided in the given link. I need to bring the 2018-2019 and 2019-2020 yield data corresponding each crop in every district from the "Kharif crop yield 18-19.xls" into "dacnet" file. These two years of data from Kharif file should be brought into dacnet file after 2017 or whichever latest previous year yield that crop contains for each district in a particular state. Since Kharif file has different format and 11-12 crops with large number of districts in each state, I am unable to get the data from Kharif to dacnet into same format.

I will really appreciate your help!

[link of both data files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dNmGTI8_c9PK1QqmfIjnpbyzuiCXgxFC%5D)

Hi @Stewart Macdonald,
I really appreciate your effort and sincere help! Really grateful to you.

The output columns of crop, district and state, showing mixed up of crop and districts. When I get the output of KharifDF it shows the same mix up of all columns, so this is getting pulled up in final output.
Can It be resolved?

Regards and Thanks,

Comment: Comments won't let you write much or format the text. You can edit your original question if you need additional help. Just edit the question, type 'Edit 1' down the bottom, and then ask your follow-up question.

Answer (score 0):

This was much trickier that I was expecting. Hopefully someone else can come up with a more efficient way, but in the meantime here's what I came up with.

Years are represented differently in `dacnet` (e.g., '2009') and `kharif` (e.g., '2018-19') files. I'm not clear on how you want to combine the two files, but I've had a go.

Read in reformat the Kharif file:

```
library('readxl') # to read Excel file
library('dplyr')
library('tidyr') # for fill()

kharifDF <- readxl::read_excel('Kharif crops yield_18-19.xls') %>% # read Excel file
  janitor::clean_names() %>% # tidy up column names
  tidyr::fill(state_crop_district, .direction='down') %>% # fill the district down so that both 2018-19 and 2019-20 rows have the district
  dplyr::mutate(
    district = stringr::str_trim(stringr::str_remove_all(state_crop_district, "[:digit:]+[\\.]")) # remove the prefix ("1.") from district
  ) %>%
  dplyr::filter(stringr::str_starts(state_crop_district, 'Total - ', negate=T)) %>% # remove these total rows
  dplyr::mutate(
    type = case_when(
      !is.na(year) ~ 'district',
      is.na(year) & lead(is.na(year)) ~ 'state',
      is.na(year) & lead(!is.na(year)) ~ 'crop',
      TRUE ~ 'district'
    ), # figure out if each row represents a state, crop, or district name
    state = case_when(
      type == 'state' ~ state_crop_district,
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    ), # add field for state
    crop = case_when(
      type == 'crop' ~ state_crop_district,
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    ) # add field for crop
  ) %>%
  tidyr::fill(state) %>% # replace missing state values with the previous state value
  tidyr::fill(crop) %>% # replace missing crop values with previous crop value
  dplyr::filter(type == 'district') %>% # remove the state and crop name rows now that we have those values in the correct columns
  dplyr::select(state, crop, district, everything(), -type, -state_crop_district) # reorder and remove unneeded columns
```

Kharif dataframe:

```
kharifDF
# A tibble: 6,969 × 8
state          crop      district      year    season area_hectare production_tonnes yield_tonnes_hectare
<chr>          <chr>     <chr>         <chr>   <chr>         <dbl> <chr>             <chr>               
  1 Andhra Pradesh Arhar/Tur ANANTAPUR     2018-19 Kharif        48972 2791              0.056991750387976804
2 Andhra Pradesh Arhar/Tur ANANTAPUR     2019-20 Kharif        39414 7922              0.20099457045719796 
3 Andhra Pradesh Arhar/Tur CHITTOOR      2018-19 Kharif         6990 1132              0.16194563662374822 
4 Andhra Pradesh Arhar/Tur CHITTOOR      2019-20 Kharif         5915 455               0.076923076923076927
5 Andhra Pradesh Arhar/Tur EAST GODAVARI 2018-19 Kharif         1406 297               0.21123755334281649 
6 Andhra Pradesh Arhar/Tur EAST GODAVARI 2019-20 Kharif          615 229               0.37235772357723579 
7 Andhra Pradesh Arhar/Tur GUNTUR        2018-19 Kharif        18948 12790             0.67500527760185769 
8 Andhra Pradesh Arhar/Tur GUNTUR        2019-20 Kharif        18004 13125             0.72900466562985999 
9 Andhra Pradesh Arhar/Tur KADAPA        2018-19 Kharif         4178 602               0.14408808042125418 
10 Andhra Pradesh Arhar/Tur KADAPA        2019-20 Kharif         4187 1482              0.35395271077143542 
# … with 6,959 more rows
```

Read in and reformat the Dacnet file:

```
dacnetDF <- read_csv('dacnet_yield_update till 2019.csv') %>% # read in csv
  janitor::clean_names() %>% # tidy up names
  dplyr::mutate(year = as.character(year)) # convert year to character, because year is a character in kharifDF

dacnetDF
# A tibble: 75,955 × 8
crop  season state_id state_name district_id district_name year  yield
<chr> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>            <dbl> <chr>         <chr> <dbl>
  1 arhar kharif     1204 Assam            15009 Barpeta       2004  0.822
2 arhar kharif     1204 Assam            15009 Barpeta       2005  0.618
3 arhar kharif     1204 Assam            15009 Barpeta       2007  0.733
4 arhar kharif     1204 Assam            15009 Barpeta       2008  0.703
5 arhar kharif     1204 Assam            15009 Barpeta       2009  0.731
6 arhar kharif     1204 Assam            15009 Barpeta       2010  0.718
7 arhar kharif     1204 Assam            15009 Barpeta       2015  0.930
8 arhar kharif     1204 Assam            15009 Barpeta       2016  0.671
9 arhar kharif     1204 Assam            15009 Barpeta       2017  0.641
10 arhar kharif     1204 Assam            15019 Jorhat        1998  0.64 
# … with 75,945 more rows
```

And now we combine them:

```
combinedDF <- dacnetDF %>%
  dplyr::bind_rows(
    kharifDF %>%
      dplyr::mutate(state_id=NA, district_id=NA, yield=as.numeric(yield_tonnes_hectare)) %>% # add in missing columns
      dplyr::select(crop, season, state_id, state_name=state, district_id, district_name=district, year, yield) # reorder and rename columns to match dacnetDF
  ) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(crop, season, state_name, year) # sort it by whichever columns you want

combinedDF
# A tibble: 82,924 × 8
crop  season state_id state_name     district_id district_name year  yield
<chr> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>                <dbl> <chr>         <chr> <dbl>
  1 arhar kharif     1202 Andhra Pradesh       15117 Adilabad      1998  0.353
2 arhar kharif     1202 Andhra Pradesh       15118 Anantapur     1998  0.332
3 arhar kharif     1202 Andhra Pradesh       15119 Chittoor      1998  0.163
4 arhar kharif     1202 Andhra Pradesh       15120 YSR           1998  0.578
5 arhar kharif     1202 Andhra Pradesh       15121 East Godavari 1998  0.142
6 arhar kharif     1202 Andhra Pradesh       15122 Guntur        1998  0.763
7 arhar kharif     1202 Andhra Pradesh       15124 Karimnagar    1998  0.37 
8 arhar kharif     1202 Andhra Pradesh       15125 Khammam       1998  0.5  
9 arhar kharif     1202 Andhra Pradesh       15126 Krishna       1998  0.568
10 arhar kharif     1202 Andhra Pradesh       15127 Kurnool       1998  0.378
# … with 82,914 more rows
```